# VARCHAR(MAX) over Availability Group slow

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an in-house application that uses 2 SQL databases.  I've had some queries in place for the last 15 years that pull data from each DB together.  These queries involve some VARCHAR(MAX) types and have always completed in 1-2 seconds.

I've recently set up some Basic Availability Groups with SQL Std 2019, therefore the 2 DBs are in separate AGs.  I have a single SQL listener.  When I run the query that spans the 2 DBs with the VARCHAR(MAX) using the listener it just hangs and eventually times out.  If I run the same query while connecting directly to the SQL instance (bypassing the listener) the query runs fine as it always has.

I narrowed it down to the issue being when pulling a VARCHAR(MAX) field from a DB in a different AG, but only when using the listener.  Does anyone know why this would be?  Luckily, the use of VARCHAR(MAX) is unnecessary and was the result of poor design ages ago.  I've since gone through and replaced all the VARCHAR(MAX)s with more reasonable field lengths and all is fine now, even using the listener.  I'd just like to know why this was happening.  I may have a legitimate need to use VARCHAR(MAX) down the road and it seems like it'll be problematic.

Thanks!

Edit:  To add to more info...  The AG replicas do span different subnets but I am using the MultiSubnetFailover=True flag in my connection string.

Comment: "When I run the query... using the listener it just hangs". Is that a connection timeout or a query timeout? I see you mention a multisubnet listener and specifying the appropriate bits on the client. To eliminate the multisubnet-ness as an issue, I'd try connecting to the listener IP of the active node and observe behavior.

Comment: Yep I've tried that, connecting direct to the listener IP to remove DNS and multi-subnet variables from the equation and it behaves the same - times out.

Comment: I still have an open question as to what you mean when you say "times out". Is it a connection timeout or a query timeout? Like, if you just do `select @@servername` over the connection, does that work? Also, when you say "the listener IP", I want to make sure that you mean "the listener IP address in the subnet that currently houses the active node in the AG" (since by its nature, a multisubnet listener will have a plurality of IPs and so saying "_the_ listener IP" is not quite accurate)

Comment: When I execute my query in Dataset Designer in Visual Studio is just says it timed out.  When I run it when connected to SSMS via the listener the query just runs seemingly forever until I cancel it.  I just ran `select @@servername` in SSMS connected via the listener and it completes fine and reports the expected server name.  And yes, when I say listener IP I'm talking about the IP for the listener in the subnet currently acting as the active node.  Thanks for helping!

Comment: If you're able run a simple query via the listener but not your actual query, that seems to rule out the listener (all credit due, you'd ruled that out but I think it was still worthwhile to get corroboration). What does SQL say that the session is waiting on when the query runs seemingly forever? That is, in another session, what does `select * from sys.dm_os_waiting_tasks where session_id = «your query's session_id»` say?

Comment: Thanks for all the input.  Since I've now changed all the VARCHAR(MAX) fields in my test environment I don't have a quick way to reproduce the issue and do more testing.  Tomorrow I'll restore an older version of the DB and run your test.  Thanks.

Comment: Well I'm at a loss now.  I've restored everything to the way it was prior to changing the VARCHAR(MAX) fields and the problem hasn't reoccurred.